# How to obtain a relevance score in a table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, relevance

I have a mysql table that has typetags for games, like

table `game_typetags`:

```
   name   typetag
--------- --------
 game#1    sports
 game#1    soccer
 game#2    race
 game#2    sports
```

and another table `games` like

```
   name   playcount 
--------- --------- 
 game#1      10      
 game#2      8
```

And I want to list relevant games (score them with number of common typetags) and sort with playcount.

So I'm trying to get such an array in PHP:

```
function getSimilarGames($typetags_array)
{
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM games COUNT (*) AS ???? ORDER BY games.playcount DESC");
}
```

So that when I call this function with `$typetags = [race,sports]` , it should return

```
name   score
____   _____
game#2   2
game#1   1
```

What query should I use for this?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with your database design, you should try to normalize it a bit but here is code that would work on your design:

```
SELECT games.name, COUNT(1) score
FROM games
INNER JOIN game_typetags ON game_typetags.name = games.name
WHERE game_typetags.typetag IN ('race', 'sports')
GROUP BY games.name
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I suggest a design like so;

```
game
-------
id integer pk
name varchar

typetag
-------
id integer pk
tagname varchar

game_typetags
-------
game_id int pk
typetag_id int pk
```

With this design you join together your tables using ID's instead of using strings everywhere.

A query to get the data you want from this could look like this, note that you could even use the tag-ids to make it tad faster (working on primary key in the database instead of string comparison in the where clause)

```
SELECT game.id, game.name, game.playcount, COUNT(1) score
FROM game
INNER JOIN game_typetags gtt ON gtt.game_id = game.id
INNER JOIN typetag tt ON tt.id = gtt.typetag_id
WHERE tt.typetag IN ('race', 'sports')
GROUP BY game.id
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. This was actually my attempt to normalize the tables by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

And I figured out a solution to this problem, as follows:

```
SELECT name, SUM(matches) as relevance_score FROM
(
SELECT
  game_typetags.*,
    (typetag =  'race'  )
+    (typetag =  'sports'  )
    AS matches
FROM game_typetags HAVING matches>0
ORDER BY matches DESC 
) a GROUP BY name ;
```